# WxPython - Writing auto completer

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm using wxPython (Phoenix).
I wrote a small app with a custom autocompleter, according to these [guidelines](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/TextCompleterSimple.html), but it fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try2.py", line 33, in <module>
    frame = TextFrame()
  File "try2.py", line 26, in __init__
    basicText.AutoComplete(MyTextCompleter)
TypeError: TextEntry.AutoComplete(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: argument 1 has unexpected type 'sip.wrappertype'
  overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'sip.wrappertype'
```

This is the code:

```
import wx
class MyTextCompleter(wx.TextCompleterSimple):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.TextCompleterSimple.__init__(self)

    def GetCompletions(self, prefix, res):
        if prefix == "a":
            res.append("This order is")
            res.append("very important")

        elif firstWord == "b":
            res.append("z - It's not in")
            res.append("a - lexicographic order")

        else:
            res.append("bye")

class TextFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Text Entry Example', size=(300, 100))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1) 
        basicLabel = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Basic Control:")
        basicText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "I've entered some text!", size=(175, -1))
        basicText.SetInsertionPoint(0)
        basicText.AutoComplete(MyTextCompleter)

        sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(cols=2, hgap=6, vgap=6)
        sizer.AddMany([basicLabel, basicText])
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = TextFrame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

When commenting out the `basicText.AutoComplete(MyTextCompleter)` it runs successfully (without the autocompletion)

Answer (score 2):

I should have warned you more thouroghly: wxPython Phoenix is the future of wxPython (because, in contrast to classic it supports Python 3, too). That said, this does not mean everything is nice and shiny. My personal advice is to keep on going with classic (or in other words: what works now in classic, will most probably also work in Phoenix). In Phoenix, you will stumble into bugs like this more often.

Luckily, in this special case, there has already been something else done:

`<wx.TextCtrl>.AutoComplete(…)` does accept a list of strings. This already works in 2.9.0/classic. See [documentation for `wx.TextEntry`/AutoComplete](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/TextEntry.html#TextEntry.AutoComplete).

Comment: Accepting a list of strings does not help me, because it applies lexicographical order on them. The whole purpose of my application is to order the autocompletes myself according to probability of usage, so I have to control the order. This is emphasized in the example in my question.

Comment: Touché. Tried also ``wx.TextCompleter``, but this method can not be overriden in wxPython. So you are out of luck (at least with wxPython builtins). At least someone [baked something up himself](https://bitbucket.org/raz/wxautocompletectrl/src/c287a0497533735ff8d233c8b69a19a6fabbf48c/autocomplete.py?at=default), but I did not test it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass an instance of MyTextCompleter, not the class itself, to wx.TextCtrl.AutoComplete().  Change this:

```
        basicText.AutoComplete(MyTextCompleter)
```

to

```
        basicText.AutoComplete(MyTextCompleter())
```